# Setting SQL variables for First day of month and 1 year before

Tags: sql, date, variables

Possibly a dumb question because I'm totally new to SQL (I mean never touched it before today ) but I'm adjusting a report in a program we use, so it always gets values for the year ending last month (we run it at the beginning of every month).
So, I want @EndDate to be either 12:59pm of the end of last month, or 00:00am of first of this month, and I want @BeginDate to be same minus 1 year. My code is getting a 'syntax error near keyword SET' - I barely even know what this means, and the past hour on google hasn't helped.

Code:

```
DECLARE @BeginDate DateTime;
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime;
SET @EndDate = CONVERT(Datetime, CONVERT(date, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GetDate()), MONTH(GetDate()),1)), -- Beginning of this month at 00:00 AM
SET @BeginDate = DATEADD(yy, -1, @EndDate) -- a year before the End date
```

This is all I've added to the existing report, so if it doesn't work completely independently it won't work at all. Over to you guys ... any suggestions? I'm guessing it's a simple, dumb mistake?

Comment: I do not see a declare statement for @BeginDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try formating it to datetime

```
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime, @BeginDate DateTime;
SET @EndDate = FORMAT(GetDate(), 'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00.000')
SET @BeginDate = DATEADD(yy, -1, @EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following. You are trying to set '@enddate' without initially declaring:

```
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime,@BeginDate DateTime;
select @EndDate = convert(datetime,datefromparts(year(getdate()),month(getdate()),1))
select @BeginDate = DATEADD(yy, -1, @EndDate) 
select @EndDate,@BeginDate
```

Comment: Sorry yes, I missed out the top line in the code quote (have now edited it). Your answer works perfectly (I'll have to remember to use select not set, perhaps?) but I've gone with @karlis ssl's answer as it simplifies the code a lot too. Us noobs prefer simple stuff. Thanks v much tho